# Determinant of a special kind of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am learning linear algebra and facing with a problem in my research. I have a special kind of matrix:
$$
M_3\left(b_1,b_2,b_3\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 b_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
 -a_1 & b_2 & a_3 \\
 -a_1 & -a_2 & b_3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
M_5\left(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5\right)\text{=}\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 b_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 \\
 -a_1 & b_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_5 \\
 -a_1 & -a_2 & b_3 & a_4 & a_5 \\
 -a_1 & -a_2 & -a_3 & b_4 & a_5 \\
 -a_1 & -a_2 & -a_3 & -a_4 & b_5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

In general form: $M_{2n-1}$.

Then I take $\det(M_{2n-1})=0$ where $b_i$ - unknowns, $i\in[1,2n-1]$.
I want to solve for $b_i$.

Some possible solution are.

For $M_3$:

$\\
b_1=a_3-a_2\\
b_2=a_1-a_3\\
b_3=a_2-a_1
$

or

$\\
b_1=0\\
b_2=0\\
b_3=0
$

For $M_5$:

$\\
b_1=-a_2-a_3+a_4+a_5\\
b_2=a_1+a_3-a_4-a_5\\
b_3=a_1-a_2-a_4+a_5\\
b_4=-a_1+a_2+a_3-a_5\\
b_5=-a_1+a_2-a_3+a_4
$

or

$\\
b_1=0\\
b_2=0\\
b_3=a_4-a_5\\
b_4=-a_3+a_5\\
b_5=a_3-a_4
$

or

$\\
b_1=0\\
b_2=0\\
b_3=0\\
b_4=0\\
b_5=0
$

I would like to know how to obtain a general solution for this.

**Edit:** The kind of solution I am interested in:

$
b_i=f(a_1,...,a_i), i\in[1,2n-1]
$

$
f(a_1,...,a_i)=k_1 a_1+k_2 a_2+...+k_i a_i, k_i\in\{0,1,-1\}.
$

Comment: The determinant is a multilinear function of the elements. In particular it is linear in each of the $b_i$s since they appear only once.  Generically, you can just pick all other variables except $b_1$ and deduce the value of $b_1$, unless you end up dividing by zero which gives rise to another subvariety of solutions.  Or are you only looking for families of solutions that consist of polynomials in the $a_i$?

Comment: @ErickWong Yes, only solutions that consist of polynomials in the $a_i$.

Comment: Ah, that’s an important constraint, you really ought to add it to the question.  Any restriction on the *degree* of the polynomials?  And you’re not interested in rational functions?  Can you provide some context for why?

Comment: @ErickWong I'm not sure if there are other solutions.
Those that were found by me seemed to me the simplest. So at first I only want to get simple solutions.
I am currently studying skew-symmetric matrices.
In the matrices given by me, the multipliers of the matrix elements are skew-symmetric.
I decided to experiment a little with the determinant. The result seemed interesting to me, so I asked about the existence of a general solution to similar problems.

Comment: There certainly are other non-polynomial solutions, such as $b_1 = - a_1 (b_2 a_3 + a_2 b_3)/(b_2 b_3 + a_2 a_3)$.  I think it would help to edit the question to clarify what you’re looking for, even if only to say that you are deliberately leaving it open-ended (in which case you could still explain your motivation and some examples of what wouldn’t be satisfactory).  That belongs in the question more than in the comments.

Comment: Sounds interesting.  I can identify a family of about $2^{2n-2}$ easy solutions.  Just multiply each column by $\pm 1$ at random, and write down the condition for “the sum of all columns is the zero vector”.  This gives a single linear equation for each $b_i$, and it should be unique up to negating the entire matrix (hence why it’s only half of $2^{2n-1}$).